# In modular arithmetic, why is $\left(g^{k_1} \bmod n\right)^{k_2} \bmod n = \left(g^{k_1}\right)^{k_2} \bmod n$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Why is $\left(g^{k_1} \bmod n\right)^{k_2} \bmod n = \left(g^{k_1}\right)^{k_2} \bmod n$ ?

<sub>Note of the editor: I used $=$ where the [original question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/63943/1) used == because $=$ in a cryptographic context is equivalent to `==` in many programming contexts (they both stand for equality, even if the former denotes an assertion and the later an operator). I rejected $\equiv$ (equivalence modulo) because there is no common notation for that in a programming context, and because there is no opening parenthesis immediately on the left of the rightmost $\bmod$, as there should be per proper notation in a cryptographic context.</sub>

Comment: Nope. Not a duplicate, it hones in on what I did not understand, is more generic, and a better question. Delete the previous one if you want, or, do whatever you want, I don't entirely understand why (g^k1 mod n)^k2 mod n == (g^k1)^k2 mod n, so, I ask.

Answer (score 4):

### Definition of $a \bmod n$

Assuming $a\in\Bbb Z$ (the signed integers) and $n\in\Bbb N^*$ (the strictly positive integers), by definition of $a\bmod n$, that is the integer $x$ such that $0\le x<n$ and $a-x$ is a multiple of $n$.

That $x$ is uniquely defined. When $a\ge 0$, that $x$ is the remainder of the [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) of $a$ by $n$. When $a<0$, that $x$ is $n-1-((1-a)\bmod n)$. We write $x=(a\bmod n)$, or just $x=a\bmod n$.

This usage of $\bmod$ coincides with `%` in most computer languages, when $a\ge 0$ at least. However that $\bmod$ operator is conventionally evaluated after evaluation of any combination of $+$, $-$, $\cdot$ (where $\cdot$ stands for multiplication) at least on the left of $\bmod$ (sometime on its right when the context makes in unambiguous), unless otherwise specified by parenthesis. That's contrary to operator `%` in most programming languages, which is typically evaluated before `+` or `-`, or before any `*` on its right, unless otherwise specified by parenthesis.

<sup>This is not to be confused with $x\equiv a\pmod n$, which means that $a-x$ is a multiple of $n$ but does not specify an interval for $x$, thus does not uniquely define $x$. That other notation is recognizable by an opening parenthesis immediately on the left of $\bmod$, or/and by the use of $\equiv$ rather than $=$. The present [question as it stands now](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/63943/3) (and the present answer except for the present paragraph) does not use that other notation, but this [slightly different question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/63938/5) does.</sup>

### Properties

It holds that $\forall a\in\Bbb Z$, $\forall b\in\Bbb Z$, $\forall n\in\Bbb N^*$
$$\begin{align}
a+b\bmod n&=(a+b)\bmod n\\
&=((a\bmod n)+b)\bmod n\\
&=(a+(b\bmod n))\bmod n\\
&=((a\bmod n)+(b\bmod n))\bmod n
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
a-b\bmod n&=(a-b)\bmod n\\
&=((a\bmod n)-b)\bmod n\\
&=(a-(b\bmod n))\bmod n\\
&=((a\bmod n)-(b\bmod n))\bmod n
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
a\cdot b\bmod n&=(a\cdot b)\bmod n\\
&=((a\bmod n)\cdot b)\bmod n\\
&=(a\cdot(b\bmod n))\bmod n\\
&=((a\bmod n)\cdot(b\bmod n))\bmod n
\end{align}$$
Of course, the simple expression on the left is usual.

In each of the three group of equalities, the first line is notational only, and the rest can be proven rigorously using properties of divisibility; in particular that if $n$ divides two integers, then $n$ divides their sum.

We'll establish that $((a\bmod n)\cdot b)\bmod n$ equals $(a\cdot b)\bmod n$, the other demonstrations are similar:

- $a\bmod n$ is (by definition of $\bmod$) the $x$ such that $0\le x<n$ and $a-x$ is divisible by $n$.
- $((a\bmod n)\cdot b)\bmod n$ is $(x\cdot b)\bmod n$ for the above $x$, thus is (by definition of $\bmod$) the $y$ such that $0\le y<n$ and $(x\cdot b)-y$ is divisible by $n$.
- $n$ divides $a-x$, thus divides the sum of $|b|$ term(s) $a-x$ (proof is by examination for $b=0$ and $|b|=1$, then by induction). Thus $n$ divides $|b|\cdot(a-x)$. Thus $n$ divides $b\cdot(a-x)$.
- $n$ divides $b\cdot(a-x)$ and $(x\cdot b)-y$, thus divides their sum $b\cdot(a-x)+((x\cdot b)-y)$.
- Per elementary algebra, the term $x\cdot b$ disappears and it follows that $n$ divides $(a\cdot b)-y$.
- $y$ is such that $0\le y<n$ and $n$ divides $(a\cdot b)-y$, therefore (by definition of $\bmod$) $y$ is $(a\cdot b)\bmod n$, Q.E.D.

It also holds that $\forall a\in\Bbb Z$, $\forall n\in\Bbb N^*$, $\forall k\in\Bbb N^*$
$$\begin{align}
a^k\bmod n&=\left(a^k\right)\bmod n\\
&=\left(\left(a\bmod n\right)^k\right)\bmod n\\
&=\left(a\bmod n\right)^k\bmod n
\end{align}$$
The first and last lines are notational only. The second line is proven for $k=1$, using that if $n$ divides $x-y$ with $0\le x<n$ and $0\le y<n$, then $x=y$; and proof for higher $k$ uses induction and the property that we derived in detail.

The desired $\left(g^{k_1}\bmod n\right)^{k_2}\bmod n=\left(g^{k_1}\right)^{k_2}\bmod n$ is merely an application of the above property, replacing $a$ by $g^{k_1}$ and $k$ by $k_2$.

Answer (score 0):

You're just taking two succesive operations, namely to the power $k_1$ and then to the power $k_2$ in the ring of integers modulo $n$, in both cases. You are just confused by the different notations for the same thing.

Comment: It's more that I lack knowledge in that particular framework. I think there's a property in modular arithmetic that I don't know about. I can reproduce the results for example, (5^11 mod 51)^9 mod 51 == 48828125^9 mod 51, but I cannot know why those are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

As fgrieu pointed out, the modulo operator is distributive across multiplication -

$ (a \cdot b) \mod n = ((a \mod n) \cdot (b \mod n)) \mod n$

Since exponentiation is just repeated multiplication, it follows that modulo is distributive across exponentiation as well.
\begin{equation}
    (g^k)^3 \mod n = (g^k \cdot g^k \cdot g^k) \mod n =\\
    ((g^k \mod n) \cdot (g^k \mod n) \cdot (g^k \mod n)) \mod n =\\
    (g^k \mod n)^3 \mod n
\end{equation}